# More helpful Mono exceptions in Mono Tools debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, mono, mono-tools

I'm getting unhandled exceptions while debugging a Mono application in Visual Studio as part of the Mono Tools for Visual Studio. The popup looks like:

[image: Popup]

I really want to be able to debug this exception, but none of the details about the exception are being captured. Additionally, if I try...catch around the line that throws the exception, the popup still occurs rather than the catch block.

I've seen this behavior occur with Mono Tools before. How do I work around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't get much support on StackOverflow, you either have to file a bug on [Novell's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.novell.com) (yes, Mono is still using it - for now at least, even though development moved to Xamarin) or emailing monotools@novell.com , as detailed on [Mono Tools support](http://mono-tools.com/support/) page. There's also a [Mono Tools forum](http://forums.mono-tools.com/) where someone might have encountered this problem as well. Previously I received fast response going through the bugzilla route, even though I also initially did not have a clean bug reproduction scenario.